# Should I get only the duplicates from both Jon and his friend first? or just get the values without getting the duplicates?

Tags: java

I'm a little confused about it.

---

Jon Panini is a collector of stickers for the world-cup. When he meets his
classmates, they usually exchange their duplicate stickers for those they do not have. Jon wishes to write a small program which allows him to input the list of sticker numbers he already has (you may assume he terminates his input with - 1), then he will input a second list of sticker numbers which his friend has (you may assume the list is terminated by -1) The program should display which sticker(s) Jon already has and which one(s) he does not.

What I did so far===>

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    ArrayList<Integer> john = new ArrayList<>();  
    ArrayList<Integer> friend = new ArrayList<>();

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    //12 7 327 7 12 34 23 79 -1
    //7 90 56 7 12 0 14 14 -1
    System.out.print("Enter Jon list of numbers(Enter -1 to terminate):");
    int i;
    do {
        i=scan.nextInt();
        if(i!=-1)
            john.add(i);
    }while(i!=-1);

    System.out.print("Enter Jon's friend list of numbers(Enter -1 to terminate):");
    do {
        i=scan.nextInt();
        if(i!=-1)
            friend.add(i);
    }while(i!=-1);

    //List for duplicates of john and and his friend
    ArrayList<Integer> johnD = new ArrayList<>();  
    ArrayList<Integer> friendD = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int j=0;j<friend.size();j++){
        for(int k=j;k<friend.size();k++){
            if(friend.get(j)==friend.get(k) && j!=k) {
                friendD.add(friend.get(j));
            }
        }
    }

    for(int j=0;j<john.size();j++){
        for(int k=0;k<john.size();k++){
            if(john.get(j)==john.get(k) && j!=k) {
                johnD.add(john.get(j));
            }
        }
    }

    ArrayList<Integer> have = new ArrayList<>();  
    ArrayList<Integer> doNotHave = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int j=0;j<friendD.size();j++){
        for(int k=0;k<johnD.size();k++){
            if(friendD.get(j)==johnD.get(k)) {
                if(!have.contains(friendD.get(j)))
                    have.add(friendD.get(j));
            }

            if(friendD.get(j)!=johnD.get(k)) {
                if(!doNotHave.contains(friendD.get(j))&& !johnD.contains(friend.get(j)))
                    doNotHave.add(friendD.get(j));
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.print("List of sticker Jon have: " + have);
    System.out.print("List of sticker Jon donot have: " + doNotHave);
    scan.close();
}
```

Comment: @deHaar He's *not* addng -1 to the lists.  He's using that as a guard value to break out of the do-while loops.

Comment: @deHaar the -1 is not added to the list... i placed a if statement in the do..while loop so that its not added. -1 is a way to exit the do..while loop... 

What I wanted to know is if i should just take the duplicates into consideration or all the value entered by the user?

Comment: @Jordan Yes, right... My comment is useless...

Comment: @JayP The wording of the assignment is kind of ambiguous, and if I were you I'd get clarification from your teacher/professor.  But based on the *intent*, I'd say that you should take the entire list into account, because no one is going to want to trade a duplicate sticker for one that they already have (and just don't have a duplicate).

Comment: @JayP you could create three lists, one holding the stickers that only jon has, one with those only the friend has and a third one with the ones both have.

Comment: @deHaar no it was not useless thank you.. :)

Comment: @Jordan Thank you... ill do that....

Comment: `Set` collection has two handy methods `removeAll` and `retainAll` that will solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be misunderstanding the question but if you are asking for advice on how to answer the prompt then I can give it a go.

After misreading the prompt itself... I think part of the prompt simply tells you that duplicates are possible but not necessary for the output since we are looking for unique entries. I would actually avoid working with duplicates in the list by cloning the lists and then removing the duplicates of the new lists. The output only asks that that we return what John has and does not have compared to his friend, not necessarily caring if there are duplicates. May also help to sort the lists before comparing.

Hoped this helped!

Comment: ohhh thank you... that what I was looking for... :D